# ubuntu 11.04 does not automount any usb drive / sd card / not even cd/dvd drive

Tags: ubuntu, mount, automount

In former version of Ubuntu I used I just had to plug in my usb drive, sd card, etc and it would show up and be mounted.
However, ever since I have 11.04 it won't do anything. I can mount it manually but, you know, that's quite annoying... :-)

So, how do I enable automounting? (not device specific, in general!)

I check with the gconf-editor that 
    apps -> nautilus -> preferences -> media_automount and media_automount_open 
is enabled

Thanks for any hints!

nandaloo